# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, woocommerce

I"m having some issues with jquery it seems. can you help me trouble shoot this problem better. I'm having an issue narrowing down the location. when I inspect element and view console I'm getting the follwoing errors.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined swatches-and-photos.js?ver=1.4.5:475
2014-08-22 14:54:48.858

I'm using woothumbs and swatches and photos and when I install the swatches and photos it gives me errors however on the website. http://codecanyon.net/item/multiple-images-per-variation-for-woocommerce/2867927?WT.ac=search_item&WT.z_author=jamesckemp

it states it completely compatible. any idea's or direction I should take to resolve?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: this.update_current = function( ) {
                this.reset_current();
         **for (var i = 0; i <              this.variations_available.length; i++) {**
   for (var attribute in            this.variations_available[ i ]) {

    var available_value = this.variations_available[ i ][attribute];
    var selected_value = this.variations_selected[attribute];
    
    if (selected_value && selected_value == available_value) {
     this.variations_current[ attribute ][ available_value ] = 1;//this is a currently selected attribute value
    } else {

     var result = true;

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the JavaScript. JS strings and arrays have a `length` property. Some part of your code expects a string or array, and wants to read its length. But the calling function does not pass a string/array but [something that evaluates to `undefined`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined swatches-and-photos.js?ver=1.4.5:475 the line of code is this  for (var attribute in this.variations_available[ i ]) {

Comment: I have downloaded that swatches-and-photos.js file, it seems like it tries to collect a number of elements from a jQuery selection. So it may be that a certain HTML element is missing or empty. Sorry that I can't be more specific, but this is a much to complex issue for the scope of a SO post.